# IMAP Encoding and decoding: UTF-8 issue

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, imap

I have a function which is meant to move a mail from one folder to another on a gmail account.
The function is fully functional when it comes to moving the mail. Tho my problem appears when
working with utf-8 encoded mailboxes. I decode the IMAP folder list response
but the dump of both values gives different results.

```
// Getting the folders
$folders = imap_list(CONNECTION, MAILBOX, PATTERN);

// After a foreach, stripping slash, prefix and such
// $folder is the raw mailbox name from the IMAP list
$mailbox = utf8_encode(imap_utf7_decode($folder)); // = string(12) "Tæstbåks"

// The entered search from the client
$search_for = "Tæstbåks"; // = string(10) "Tæstbåks"

if($search_for == $mailbox)
    print "Yeah!";
else
    print "Noo!";
```

I do not know why those two strings do not match, that is my problem.

Comment: Print the `bin2hex()` of both. Also, why are you using `utf8_encode`?

Comment: I am using the `utf8_encode()` to format it correct for viewing. Tryed dosins of different encodings and this were the only method returning the mailbox in a right format.

Regarding the `bin2hex()` function the return value of both is as follows:
IMAP Mailbox = string(24) "5400c3a673746200c3a56b73"
Serach_for = string(20) "54c3a6737462c3a56b73"
So they still don't match

Comment: But it just converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. If your input is not ISO-8859-1, then it will fail as you can see.

Comment: Yes but at least you can see why they don't match, the first one has 2 `NUL`s

Comment: I see what you mean, but how do i make them match?

Comment: You can remove `NULs` with `str_replace("\x00", "", $str)` but I wonder where they came from in the first place

Answer (score 5):

PHP's function `imap_utf7_decode($folder)` is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf7-decode.php) to return a string in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Given that IMAP's modified UTF-7 scheme can encode the whole range of Unicode (which means "a lot") and that ISO-8859-1 can only represent 256 individual characters, you cannot possibly use that function in this context. I would go as far as to suggest that the PHP developer who decided to offer such a useless function was not in his best shape the day he designed it.

It looks like the mbstring extension can do what you really want to do here -- use something like `$mailbox = mb_convert_encoding($folder, "UTF-8", "UTF7-IMAP")`, as suggested in the comments below the PHP's docs.

Comment: +1 for helping me out. I took your code and changed it slightly and it worked from me... here is my code to help the next guy `mb_convert_encoding($msg, "UTF-8", "auto");`